# instance variable being changed unexpectedly

Tags: python, oop, recursion, instance-variables, self

Trying to recurse through directories to find files that are not in both orig and dest directories. When I recurse into directories, I pass along a previous directory variable so that I know the working directory structure within the source directory (because the working directories match on both orig & dest directories).

If my first working directory is *'dirA'*, then the variable `self.working` becomes *'dirA'*. If I go into *'dirA/dirB'* and pass `self.working` back up to the recurse method, then (what I think is a new instance of) the variable `working` becomes *'dirA/dirB'*. When it's done in *'dirB'* and returns to *'dirA'*, `self.working` is still *'dirA/dirB'*.

If I simply take `self.` off of `working`, everything works as expected (because `working` is now a static variable?). When I call `self.recurse`, this does create a new instance of recurse correct? I'm also passing a new list as an instance variable, but nothing weird happens to that.

I guess a follow up question would be: when should I be explicitly declaring instance variables, and when should I just take in the variables that are passed in with the method?

Here is a streamlined version of the code that wasn't working. I've pulled out all of the other stuff cause this is the only issue I have with it, and the rest doesn't effect this portion. I'm creating the *'dirA'* & *'dirB'* lists in the `if` clauses because in the actual code I create a list of the current directory contents there.

```
source = 'dirS/'
c_SD_list = ['dirA', 'fileA']

class checkFiles(object):
    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = source

    def recurse(self, current_list, working):
        self.current_list = current_list
        self.working = working
        for a in self.current_list:
            self.full = self.working + a
            if a == 'dirA':
                self.new_list = ['dirB', 'fileA_1', 'fileA_2']
                self.recurse(self.new_list, self.full + '/')
            elif a == 'dirB':
                self.new_list = ['fileB_1', 'fileB_2']
                self.recurse(self.new_list, self.full + '/')
            else:
                print(self.source + self.full)

checker = checkFiles(source)
checker.recurse(c_SD_list, '')
```

I've googled for half the day, read old questions on here, documents and posts describing instance variables, OOP in general, etc... still haven't been able to understand why this is happening. So if I missed the answer that someone already put up, please forgive me and kindly point it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callling `self.recurse()` does not create any new objects, so `self.current_list` will point to the same object.

If you want to make a new object when you recurse, try `checkFiles(self.source).recurse()`

EDIT:
In response to your follow-up question:

You should only be making instance variables if they reflect some quality of that object, and not the state of some function. And as a personal style note, you generally shouldn't be creating them outside of your constructor, but that's up to personal taste.

Comment: `self.working` doesn't change as it goes up the tree, because it still points to the same object. If you want working to remain between calls, don't have it as an instance attribute, just a local variable.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thanks!

One other question, why do you suggest not creating instance variables outside of the constructor?